# How can I get appsync API endpoint in serverless configure file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-appsync

I am using `serverless` to deploy an Appsync API and a few lambda functions. This plugin https://github.com/sid88in/serverless-appsync-plugin is used to deploy Appsync. The lambda and Appsync are defined in the same `serverless.yml` file and they are deployed altogether.

My lambda needs to know the Appsync API endpoint which is created during `sls deploy`. How can I reference the Appsync endpoint as environment variable to my lambda?

my `serverless.yml`:

```
function:
   myHandler:
      handler: src/lambdas.myHandler
      name: myHandler
      environment:
        ENDPOINT: # HERE, how can I get appsync endpoint url?

custom:
  appSync:
    name: ${self:provider.stackName}
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AppSync plugin exposes a variable `GraphQlApi` which you can tap into for your environment variables which are automatically accessible in your lambdas.

In your config:

```yaml
environment:
  API_URL: { Fn::GetAtt: [ GraphQlApi, GraphQLUrl ] }
```

In your lambda:

```js
process.env.API_URL
```

Or lambda config directly:

```yaml
  name: myHandler
  environment:
    ENDPOINT: { Fn::GetAtt: [ GraphQlApi, GraphQLUrl ] }
```

Comment: Is `Ref::GraphQlApi` the right syntax? I have tried and `API_URL` has value of `Ref::GraphQlApi` rather than the real value.

Comment: Try it with `Fn::GetAtt: [ GraphQlApi, GraphQLUrl ] }` . Forgot `Ref::GraphQlApi` only works directly in CloudFormation sections

Comment: Yes it works. I am currently having only one appsync API. How does it support multiple API?

Comment: You prefix it with the name: `MyReallyCoolGraphQlApi`